# How to find the highest temperature recorded on each day

Tags: influxdb

I am working on InfluxDb and have a time series data which records temperature of a location. Here i have to find the max temp and the time stamp for each day.

The task is to:

- Find the mean temperature on 1 hour basis.
- Then find the max temperature from the above mean for each day.

I have wrote a query but I'am not getting the output as required.

```
SELECT MAX(mean)
FROM (SELECT mean("value")
        FROM "temperature"
        WHERE ("location" = 'L1')
        GROUP BY time(1h))
    GROUP BY time(1d)
```

I'am getting the output as:

```
time                 max 
----                 ---      
2020-01-17T00:00:00Z 573.44
2020-01-16T00:00:00Z 674.44
```

**Here am getting the time stamp as 00:00:00z is there a way to get the exact time i.e if mean temp is 573.44 at 13:00 hour on 2020-01-17, The timestamp should be 2020-01-17T13:00:00Z**

Comment: BTW: Your query doesn't find max daily value. It finds only max from hourly mean values.

Comment: ```SELECT max("value")
        FROM "temperature"
        WHERE ("location" = 'L1')
        GROUP BY time(1d)``` . or am i missing somthing

Comment: @JanGaraj i have updated the question. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Currently, no.

`GROUP BY` effectively removes per-entry timestamps. It's like all the data for the grouping interval (e.g. for the day) gets dropped into a bucket without their timestamps. The bucket has a single timestamp - the start of the interval.

The result only ever has the timestamp of the start of the `GROUP BY` interval.

The only way to do this is in the app, not the backend. You might want to experiment; if you only need resolution down to the e.g. nearest 5 minutes, do the query using `GROUP BY time(5m)`. This can be done to shrink the size of data retrieved by the client vs backend processing time.

Comment: Thank you Jason for your reply. Got a fair idea how group by clause will work in influxDb, but the group by 5m won't solve my requirement as I have to find the peak hour per day.

Comment: If you only need 1h resolution, then it might make sense to use your inner query to get the data, and process that, i.e. `SELECT mean("value") FROM "temperature" WHERE ("location" = 'L1') GROUP BY time(1h)`. This reduces your data transfer significantly, and the app load too.